# Tomcat error 500 when using JAXB

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jersey, tomcat7

I used a rest web service using **jersey** (followed this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DY46f-LZ0M) and everything works fine.
Now I am trying to use a WS which returns a basic **JSON**.
When I try and use it via browser I get this error
**HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception**

**Question:**

**Where should I investigate further?**

I am using: Eclipse JEE, jersey-archive-1.18, Tomcat 7

THis is my class:

```
package com.name.rest.status;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/v1/status")
public class V1_status {

private static final String api_version = "1.00.1";
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String returnTitle() {
    return "<p> Java Web Service </p>";     
}


@Path("/version")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String returnVersion() {
    return "<p> version is: <p>" + api_version;     
}

@GET 
@Produces("/application/json")
public MyJaxbBean getMyBean() {
return new MyJaxbBean("Agamemnon", 32);
}
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>com.name.rest</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>readme.html</welcome-file>  
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.property.packages</param-name>  
<param-value>com.name.rest</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
<param-value>com.name.rest</param-value>
</init-param>

<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here my exception:

```
mensaje Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception



javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:50 2)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)


    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.text.ParseException: Next event is not a Token
com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createQualitySourceMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:289)
com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createQualitySourceMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:274)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.addProduces(IntrospectionModeller.java:173)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.workOutResourceMethodsList(IntrospectionModeller.java:303)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:126)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1595)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1356)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)


    java.text.ParseException: Next event is not a Token
com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.nextToken(HttpHeaderReader.java:102)
com.sun.jersey.core.header.QualitySourceMediaType.valueOf(QualitySourceMediaType.java:84)
com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader$5.create(HttpHeaderReader.java:360)
com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader$5.create(HttpHeaderReader.java:358)
com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readList(HttpHeaderReader.java:481)
com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readList(HttpHeaderReader.java:473)
com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readAcceptableList(HttpHeaderReader.java:461)
com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readQualitySourceMediaType(HttpHeaderReader.java:365)
com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readQualitySourceMediaType(HttpHeaderReader.java:373)
com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createQualitySourceMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:287)
com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createQualitySourceMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:274)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.addProduces(IntrospectionModeller.java:173)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.workOutResourceMethodsList(IntrospectionModeller.java:303)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:126)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1595)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1356)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Produces` annotation on `getMyBean()` method should be

`@Produces("application/json")`

instead of

`@Produces("/application/json")`

(remove the leading `/`)

Alternatively, you can use the constants defined in`javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType`. That way you'll be aware of mistakes at compile time. For example:

`@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Comment: It does not give me that error anymore, but the page is displayed as blank. I call it this way: http://localhost:8081/com.name.rest/api/v1/status/application/json

Comment: The resource is available at `localhost:8081/com.name.rest/api/v1/status` (you do not have `@Path("application/json")` on `getMyBean` so you can't use the URI you're using).

Comment: @MichalGajdos is right, `application/json` is not part of the path.  Since you have two `GET` methods your client will need to specify the desired type in the request's [`Accept`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) header.
i.e., if you want html use `Accept: text/html`, if you want json use `Accept: application/json`.